# SyncXHR in Page Dismissal Alternative

Tags: xmlhttprequest

Since google has declared to [disallow sync XHR in page dismissal](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4664843055398912), i havent found the decent replacement to this feature. I've tried sendBeacon, but the 64KB payload limit makes it useless for my use case. At this point, i found the workaround by configuring the chromium flag directly (#allow-sync-xhr-in-page-dismissal). But this is clearly not the final solution. It's not user friendly to force your user to tweak their own browser in order to use our app.

Is there any syncXHR in page dismissal alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xhr;
function saveChanges(){
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST',url,false)
  xhr.send(post)
}
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) =>{
  saveChanges();
  if(xhr.readyState == 4) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = '';
})
```

Credit to : https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/LnqwTCiT9Gs/m/wM0yAjcfAAAJ